# Error in tree: contains duplicate file entries

Tags: git

Having an issue moving an existing repo to another origin where it's claiming a tree has duplicate file entries.

`git fsck --full 
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done. 
error in tree 4ef325894daeb3a7eeaba4cb7b40b43844f2974c: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries 
Checking objects: 100% (25808/25808), done.`

When I run `git show 4ef325894daeb3a7eeaba4cb7b40b43844f2974c` on the hash for the tree it's showing two directories.

```
Controllers/   
Controllers/
```

I've tried making a new tree to replace the broken one but the issue still persists, it could be that I'm doing it on the wrong tree but I'm not sure as there are two trees.

`git ls-tree 4ef325894daeb3a7eeaba4cb7b40b43844f2974c
040000 tree fc9af05207cd34539b6b0fe81ce7a3f1370d4750    Controllers
040000 tree fc9af05207cd34539b6b0fe81ce7a3f1370d4750    Controllers`

[image: Example of trees]

Comment: Yes, tree object `4ef325894daeb3a7eeaba4cb7b40b43844f2974c` is definitely broken. What's the *question* though? Git presumably checks out the entity OK...

Comment: The question is how can I fix it? and push the code with the history to a new repo.

Comment: You will need to copy at least some of the repository's commits to new commits, during which process the bad tree object (with duplicate entries) is copied to a new (no duplicate entry) good tree object. The new tree will have a different ID, which will affect the commit(s) that contain it, which will cause those commits to have new IDs, which will bubble forward through the rest of the history. Since I don't have the bad repository I can't *test* this but it seems likely that a `git filter-branch` over the entire repository should work.

Comment: Probably `git filter-branch ` with noop `--index-filter` would be enouth

Comment: `git replace --edit` can make such broken trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience you need to create a new tree to replace the broken one.

Either that or if the history of the repo is not as important. You can delete .git folder and it should allow you to push without issue.